# Proper proof that subgroup of a vector space is a sub-space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space.

Proove that if $U\subseteq V$ is a non - empty sub-group that is closed to addition and scalar multipication, then $U$ is a subspace.

This is my way of approaching this:

$U\subseteq V$, then each property of $V$ applies to $U$ (each one of the vector space axioms)

then i'll show that foreach $\alpha, \beta \in U$ and foreach scalar, each one of the 8 vector space axioms take place in $U$, then $U$ must be a vector space, therefore a sub-space of $V$.

I feel like my way of approaching this is certainly an - over-kill. i'd love to hear reccomendations from you guys!

Comment: What definition of subspace are you using?

Comment: @JacobCheverie A sub-space is a subgroup of a vector space that is non-empty (contains the zero vector), closed to addition, and to scalar multicipation

Comment: That is what you are trying to prove, no? You must have a formal definition of subspace that you must conform to.

Comment: @JacobCheverie that's why it is so odd to me. that's the formal defenition that we use. and that's what Im asked to prove.

Comment: You are given that $U$ is non-empty and closed under addition and scalar multiplication. Thus, by definition of subspace, it is a subspace?

Comment: @JacobCheverie Well, it appears that this question was dumb in the first place, they just wanted us to multiply by 0 scalar and thus show that the zero vector exists. sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: There are two definitions of subspace: a non-empty subset of a vector space that is closed under addition and scalar multiplication, **or** a vector space that is contained in another vector space, with the same operations. Maybe you're supposed to prove the latter?